# Dropbox Api, get user History

Tags: c#, sdk, dropbox-api

Is there a way to track user history of changes in dropbox?
I have a windows form application using dropbox Api where user can perform changes in it like (Add,delete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for webhooks, here is a link https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks